Object reference not set to an instance of an object. Tablero ajedrez
Estoy intentando hacer una validación de que si ya existe una dama en un tablero de ajedrez, sin embargo al querer realizar la validación me tira una exception en la linea de la condición del if. Supuestamente era porque el problema no podia aceptar posibles valores nulls, por eso esta la otra condición de que si no es nulo, pero me tira la misma exception, "Object reference not set to an instance of an object.".
public bool DamaExiste()
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < piezasTab.GetLength(0); i++) //fila
      {
         for (int j = 0; j < piezasTab.GetLength(1); j++) //columna
         {
            if (piezasTab[i, j].Tipo != null)
            {
               if (piezasTab[i, j].Tipo == "Dama")
               {
                  return false;
               }
            }
         }
      }
      return true;
   }


Realizas la validaciòn de
if (piezasTab[i, j].Tipo != null)

pero en este caso piezasTab[i, j] puede ser null, por lo que debes agregar tambièn esta validaciòn:
  if (piezasTab[i, j] != null && piezasTab[i, j].Tipo != null)

Realiza el cambio en tu còdigo:
public bool DamaExiste()
   {
      for (int i = 0; i < piezasTab.GetLength(0); i++) //fila
      {
         for (int j = 0; j < piezasTab.GetLength(1); j++) //columna
         {
            if (piezasTab[i, j] != null && piezasTab[i, j].Tipo != null)
            {
               if (piezasTab[i, j].Tipo == "Dama")
               {
                  //return false;
                    return true; //*Es tipo Dama
               }
            }
         }
      }
      //return true;
      return false; 
   }


¿La última línea no tendría que retornar false? De otra forma la función siempre va a retornar true.

Gracias @jachguate , se supone hice el cambio, pero deje el mismo valor haha!

Ahora si, +1 :D. Un saludo!
